# "Redirect not allowed here" - I cannot get htaccess to work even with AllowOveride All

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have just set up apache, everything was working but when I tried to use .htaccess I got a 500 internal server error. I checked the logs and it said `"Redirect not allowed here"`

Here is my htaccess file: `Redirect 302 / http://home.dev/test`

And my apache configuration: http://pastebin.com/B7Ah2dSB (I couldn't format it on the page because the hashed comments turned to headings)

Finally the httpd-vhosts configuration:

```
<Directory "/Users/georgearnall/public">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>  
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/georgearnall/public"
  ServerName home.dev
</Virtualhost>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should try moving the `<Directory>` block inside the `<Virtualhost>` block. And, of course, be sure to restart Apache following any change.

Comment: I couldn't see anything in your configuration that would override your Directory directive, but it is possible that there is something in an included file. However, if you place the Directory directive within the Virtualhost directive it will be applied much later in the processing order which might be what you need.

Also, I don't think you need a VirtualDocumentRoot directive unless your doing interpolation into the directory string.

Comment: I moved the `<Directory>` block inside the `<Virtualhost>` block, restarted and still the same issue. 
I also removed VirtualDocumentRoot and still nothing.
The `.htaccess` file is definatley enabled. I got the following error: `Invalid command 'asdf'...`.

Comment: Change `VirtualDocumentRoot` to `DocumentRoot` and restart Apache

Comment: No change, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it! I was checking in the processes and apache was never restarted. 
I was using this command: `sudo apachectl restart` but it did not work.
Instead I used `sudo killall httpd` and then `sudo apachectl start`.